# A bogus proof of countable power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

I know that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is not countable but what is wrong with the following "proof"?

Consider the following map $f: \mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$, which maps a natural number $n$ to a set of integers which correspond to *the index* of non-zero bits in $n$'s binary representation:

$$f(n)=\{i ~|~ n = \sum_{j=0}^\infty k_j2^j \text{ and } k_i=1\}$$

$f(n)$ is clearly "onto" since for any $S\in 2^\mathbb{N}$, there exists a natural number $n = \sum_{i\in S} 2^i$ s.t. $f(n)=S$.

However, if $f(n)$ is onto, then this is effectively proving that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is countable, which is, of course, false. Where was the mistake?

Comment: I admire your use of the term "bogus"

Comment: Just look for the word "clearly". Works every time.

Comment: "there exists a natural number $n=∑_{i∈S}2^i$" ... No, there doesn't.  That's not a natural (finite) number if there are infinite 1's in the index.  And there *will* be some S with infinite 1s in the index.  This function most certain is *NOT* onto.

Comment: @fleablood "That's not a natural (finite) number..." does natural number has to be finite?

Comment: "Does a natural number have to finite?"  Uh,  yes!

Comment: To be perfectly frank "for any S there exists a natural number" really should have evoked a "what?!?! Of course there aren't!" response.  This proof should be about as convince ing as a "list all the real numbers in a list in any order, index the first as one and the second as 2-- clearly for every real number there is an index".  It's no more legitimate than that and it shouldn't "feel" any better.

Comment: My formal answer: the proof assumes the readers naivety will not understand the difference between {all n-tuples for any value n} and {all sequences}.  The first *is* countable by the argument but the second is not.  The first set contains n-tuples of any possible length but every n-tuples is of some finite length.  The second set includes sequences that may be infinite in length.  For any infinite sequence S $n=\sum_{i \in S}2^i $ is an infinite sum and is "clearly" *!NOT!* a natural number.  So f is clearly *not* onto.

Answer (score 26):

The range of the function includes only the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$. If $S$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$, then $\sum_{i\in S}2^i$ is not defined.

Answer (score 15):

The mistake is that you assume that you assumed $S \in 2^{\Bbb N}$ is a *finite set*.  In fact, your statement constitutes a valid proof that there are countably many *finite subsets* of $\Bbb N$, which is certainly a useful bit of information.

Note that if you look at infinite sums of the form $\sum_{i} k_i2^{-i+1}$, you end up with a surjective map to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Surjective and almost bijective, aside from a painful technicality. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe worth noting that this *does* give a proof of a bijection $\mathbb{Z}_2  \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ between the $2$-adic integers and the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, since the $2$-adic integers *are* in one-to-one correspondence with such binary nmerals.